# Using CrystaX with Qt to build android application: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt5

I am trying to build `Qt application` for android using `Qt Creator`. I use `CrystaX NDK` for android instead of goolge's one because I need to use `boost libraries` in my project, and, as CrystaX's official site says, it is comes with it.

I am using following versions of tools:

- Qt Creator 3.4.2
- Qt 5.5.0
- CrystaX NDK 10.2.1

At first, I had to manually add libraries and headers paths in my `.pro` file, because it hasn't been found automatically. There was compiler error: `can't locate libcrystax`, there was some errors in source files about including `boost headers`. I've added following lines in my project file:

```
android {
    INCLUDEPATH +=  $$NDK_ROOT/sources/crystax/include \
                    $$NDK_ROOT/sources/boost/1.58.0/include \
                    $$PWD/ssl
    LIBS += -L"$$PWD/ssl" -lssl -lcrypto
    LIBS += -L"$$NDK_ROOT/sources/crystax/libs/$$ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH"
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = $$NDK_ROOT/sources/crystax/libs/$$ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH/libcrystax.so
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
}
```

After rebuilding again, I've got an error (`runtime error`) that says `libgnustl_shared requires libcrystax, but libcrystax is not loaded` or something similar.

After searching the internet, I've found that it's happening because one library that requires another, is loading before it, and that second library, is not being searched for, at application directory, only in system paths.

I've found a workaround - to load required library manually. I copied default `QtActivity.java` into my project directory (`android/src/.../QtActivity.java`) to replace default one and added following code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary( "crystax" );
}
```

After that I am not getting that error, but now I'm stuck with another one:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:    37 cannot locate '__aeabi_ldiv0'...`

Is it possible to use `Qt + CrystaX NDK` for build android app? Am I doing it wrong way? Please, explain how to do it properly, if I've mistaken or if I misunderstood whole concept. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you haven't linked with `libgcc.a`. I don't know how exactly your build system works (well, Qt's one), but generally, adding libgcc.a to the list of additional libraries should help:

```
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = $$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/libgcc.a
```

This line specify `arm` variant of `libgcc.a`; obviously, you should use proper one depending on `ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH` value.

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
Could you please look at nm output for libgcc.a file? Is it ok, that it has two undefined symbols and one weak for that name (`__aeabi_ldiv0`)?

`nm $$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/armv7-a/libgcc.a | grep ldiv0`:

`U __aeabi_ldiv0`,  `U __aeabi_ldiv0`, `00000000 W __aeabi_ldiv0`

Comment: Yes, it's ok. This is how `libgcc.a` is constructed - it is built from bunch of object files (.o), two of them require `__aeabi_ldiv0` (so it appears as `U __aeabi_ldiv0` in nm output), and one define it (so it appears as `W __aeabi_ldiv0` in nm output). The reason why it define `__aeabi_ldiv0` as weak symbol it to allow developer replace it if needed - for example, providing alternative, more optimized, version. However, if developer don't want to replace it by own version, it will just work.

Comment: Thank you! I've figured out that `libgnustl_shared` requires `libcrystax` to load,  while `libQt5Core` requires `libgnustl_shared` to load. `libQt5Core.so` built using `Google NDK` and provided by Qt 5 framework. And I am trying to build android package, using `CrystaX NDK`. So the package is completed with `libgnustl_shared` from `Crystax NDK` and `libQt5Core`, which expect `libgnustl_shared` from `Google NDK`. Can this be a reason of that error? I've already linked with `libgcc.a` manually, but seems that it was excessive, since it was already linked by build tool.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say what is exact reason of the error in your case. It actually depends very much on Qt's build system, which I'm not aware of. I have plans to look on Qt, and publish article about usage Qt + CrystaX NDK, but it's not yet done.

However, typically it's better to build all binaries with either Google's Android NDK or with CrystaX NDK, not interleaving them. In CrystaX NDK, we don't guarantee binary compatibility with Google's Android NDK, we only guarantee that CrystaX NDK can be used as a drop-in replacement of Google's one.